# Spheroid distance to sphere distance

Tags: geometry, geometry-conversion, turf

I have

- linestring that is calculated on a spheroid.
- Shpere distance of where the point should be on the linestring
- Distance spheroid / sphare.

On one lib, its all calculated in spheroid (Normal map).
Other lib uses sphare.

Lets say the total distances are:
Spheroid: 76363.06884857068
Sphere: 82238.6290291082
The sphareoidic distance from the start would be 409, I need to get distance from spheres perspective.

Any tips where should I look?